# UITextfield subclass not responding to insertText: method of UIKeyInput protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield, uikeyinput

I want to observe the text input in a `UITextfield` subclass. For that I m trying to implement `UIKeyInput` protocol methods in that subclass. But the `insertText:` and `hasText` methods are never called. However `deleteBackward` method is called. Do you know why these methods are not called. When I test the same scenario with `UIView` subclass I have seen that  all the methods in `UIKeyInput` protocol are called.

If this does not work is there any other way to notice the text input in a `UITextField` subclass?

I know about the `UITextFieldDelegate`'s `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` method. But I want to control the character entry in the `UITextField`'s subclass and not by its delegate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `UITextField` is using `UITextInput` protocol for this functionality. Perhaps you can use `UITextField` to be delegate of itself.

Comment: I tried using UITextInput protocol but still the insertText: method is not called. I want to create a generic UITextField's subclass that can control the character entry in itself. And I want to leave the flexibility for other classes to assign the delegate of the UITextField's subclass object to any object they want.